# Campos nulos, Laravel y Mysql

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo una API con Laravel, Mysql y Angular. En el lado del back-end con Laravel estoy enviando los datos para guardarlos en la base de datos usando SOLID. El código funcionaba bien antes de implementar el primer principio de SOLID en mi proyecto.

Desde EmployeeController.php llamo el método:

```
/**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Employee  $employee_id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $employee_id) //Se usa para actualizar un usuario en la tabla de la DB.
    {
        //
        EmployeeUpdate::Actualizar($request, $employee_id);
    }
```

Esta es la clase que cree para cumplir el primer principio de SOLID. El archivo EmployeeUpdate.php:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Employee;

use App\Models\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmployeeUpdate{

    public static function Actualizar(Request $request, $employee_id){
        
        $employee           = Employee::find($employee_id); //Vamos a buscar el id del empleado
        $employee->id       = $request->input('id');
        $employee->name     = $request->input('name');
        $employee->address  = $request->input('address');
        $employee->phone    = $request->input('phone');
        $employee->email    = $request->input('email');
        $employee->save();
        
        //imprimir en formato json
        echo json_encode($employee);
    }
}
?>
```

Este es el error que me da:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null (SQL: update `employees` set `id` = ?, `name` = ?, `address` = ?, `phone` = ?, `email` = ?, `employees`.`updated_at` = 2021-03-20 00:50:24 where `id` = 5) in file C:\php\aureostock\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 678
```

Cabe aclarar que el archivo EmployeeUpdate.php está una carpeta llamada Employee en la ruta App\Http\Employee\ y el archivo EmployeeController.php está en la ruta App\Http\Controllers

Gracias de antemano. <3

Comment: podrias mostrar como estas definiendo la ruta y como envias la data, supongo que es desde un fetch o axios

Comment: ¿Por qué si es una operación de actualizar vas a modificar el id?, por otro lado te da dicho error por que no le esta llegando valor alguno para el atributo `id` ¿seguro que quieres actualizar ese atributo?

Comment: Revisastes si `$request->input('id')` tiene algun dato? Y como dice @BetaM ¿Para que actualizar el id? Lo que haces seria lo mismo que un `insert`